# How to speed up rendering a plotly charts?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am currently preparing a shiny app that shows demographics for my country. I am using the plotly package for data visualization. All the graphs are great, but the problem is that they render very slowly. That is, when I start the application, I have to wait about 30 seconds for the graphs to appear on the screen. Is there any way to speed up the rendering of the graphs and make them appear on the screen much faster? I think the maximum delay can be 2-3 seconds, I wouldn't want more. I have a 8 or 9 graphs per page so honestly, I don't want to believe that the R language and the plotly package that are designed for data visualization work so poorly with such a number of graphs, so I'm considering some mistakes on my own. I found this guide: https://plotly-r.com/performance.html
however, the first way `toWebGL ()` doesn't work at all, and using the second function `partial_bundle ()` I have the impression that the graphs render even slower. So, are there any other ways to speed up the rendering of the graphs? What errors should I watch out for in the code so as not to slow down the rendering of the graphs?  I will be grateful for all tips, advice, and in particular for suggestions to solve the problem.

The problem seems general to me, so I do not add my code, but if necessary I will of course add it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [profiling your code](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-with-RStudio) to see where the bottleneck is? It can get complicated with shiny and plotly addons but it should at least give you a clue. If you run the code outside of the shiny app is it still a problem? The fact that it's slow on startup means that it might not be a plotly/shiny question but instead may have to do with your initial data processing

Comment: @Dubukay Thank you so much for all clues. 
I will try to profile my code and also run it outside the application. 
Indeed, I didn't say how I store and process the data before "drawing" the chart. I keep all the data in data frames, I do not perform any operations on them when drawing the graph. I just point to specific columns. So it seems to me that in this matter it cannot be easier since I provide ready-made data. However, can you say if at first glance I could improve something in the storage / processing of my data?

Comment: Sure! I work a lot with Shiny and plotly so I know speed can be a pain when you want it to be highly interactive. My load times are often slow because my files are ~500 MB in size, so I had some luck speeding up load times by saving things as .RData files and reading them with load() rather than read.csv(). How big is your data set? I guess your comment about it taking a long time on startup made me assume it's reasonably speedy once within the app, which is what I'd expect if it took a long time to load but the actual drawing/plotting was relatively speedy.

Comment: @Dubukay 
I use 16 data frames in my application. Each of them has exactly 15 rows and 29 columns. So I really don't think it's too much for R. However, my application has 16 tabs (each tab separately for 1 region) and in one tab I use only one data frame. I forgot to mention it before, but after starting the application, it loads about 30 seconds, next all the graphs appear, some are interactive and then they run smoothly. However, when I switch to another tab, I have to wait about 30 seconds again before the charts for this region are loaded on it.

Comment: @Dubukay Could it matter? Maybe I have too many data frames / tabs? Maybe I should collect all the data in one frame? I went into deep water with this app so maybe I'm asking for the basics, but I'd be grateful for any more tips

Comment: Yeah, that definitely shouldn't be too much for R to handle and it should be very quick. Did you have any luck checking how long they take to render outside of the shiny app? I haven't made any shiny apps with that many tabs but it shouldn't be a major factor, I'd assume. The 30 second load per tab does imply it's something about the reactivity or plotting that's slowing things down because each tab will "react" only when it's the chosen one.

Comment: @Dubukay I tried to render the graphs outside the application, then the time for one graph is about 5 seconds before it appears on the screen. To be honest, I don't know if the application is rendering all the graphs at once or in sequence (but when I start the application, they all appear on the screen at the same time), so I'm not sure what conclusion I should draw. However, I was not able to profile my code, but I will try to learn more about it if it does not solve the problem in another way.